# TinyMCE - Allow text as direct child of table

Tags: angular, tinymce

I have a problem with tinyMCE upload html

My upload html:

```html
<table>
   %%[ if not empty(@hl_txt) then ]%%
  <tr><td>welcome<td></tr>
  %%[ endif ]%%
</table>
```

After upload in editor, below is the new html

```html
%%[ if not empty(@hl_txt) then ]%% %%[ endif ]%%
 <table> <tr><td>welcome</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

All content in TinyMCE is valid HTML. As stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table), `<table>` elements may only contain (in this order):

- an optional `<caption>` element
- zero or more `<colgroup>` elements,
- an optional <`thead>` element,
- either one of the following:

  - zero or more `<tbody>` elements
  - one or more  elements
- an optional `<tfoot>` element

Thus, TinyMCE does not recognize your markup as valid HTML. It parses and reorders the data to the outside of the table element to ensure all HTML is valid.